# Running "Last" Linux Command

Tags: php, linux, exec, shell-exec

I'm trying to execute a linux command in PHP, here is my sample code:

```
$command = "last -F";
$o = shell_exec($command);
print_r($o);
```

Most of the Linux commands gives me an output, but for the `Last -F` command, I have no output. Why is it so?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right permissions?

Comment: Most likely a permission issue. This works fine for me.

Comment: how do you change the permission to have PHP Script execute the command?

Comment: Well it depends on how you executing your script. If it's CLI, then it uses a user which is executing this command (so this user should have appropriate permissions). If you're executing this script from the web browser, then it's most likely user called www-data. You should give appropriate permissions to this user then.

Answer (score 0):

Try [This Explaination](http://chipmunkninja.com/Program-Execution-in-PHP%3a-exec-m@).  Your issue MAY be that the last line of `last -F` is a new-line.  `shell_exec()` only returns the last line of the command, and therefore, if that line is empty, you get nothing, nada.

As an alternative, try `exec()`, this will allow you to capture the return value (success or failure of execution) as well as the entirety of the command's output.  Check it out [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Answer (score 0):

You are executing that command as web user (`nobody` or `www-data`), which is a limited privileged user.You have to execute that command as root. Unfortunately giving sudo permission or full permission to web user is really a bad idea. So I recommend make a cron or background script that execute `last -F` and write output to a file. You can read that file from your PHP script.

You can make a script runs in background like this.

```
   #!/bin/bash

    while [ true ]; do
         last -F > /tmp/myfile
    done
```

save the code as mycron.sh

```
chmod +x mycron.sh
mycron.sh &
```

Read the file `/tmp/myfile` from your PHP Program. It will give the exact output of that command.